# How can I generate a periodic report or dashboard for Salesforce Bulk API Usage within a particular org?

Tags: batch, reporting, tooling-api

I want to be able to capture on which user is running the batch jobs and how many bulk API batches are being used on a daily basis.  We would like to track the 24 hour bulk A batch limit .

I am aware of SF event Monitoring event but that doesn't give batch count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the Limits API with a GET request, where 'XX.X' is your version:

GET /services/data/vXX.X/limits

Your response map will include

```
  "DailyBulkApiRequests" : {
    "Max" : 10000,
    "Remaining" : 10000,
  }
```

as well as a more granular breakdown.

You can find more information on what you can dig into with that call here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm